# How to set a timeout for multiple child process

Tags: c, linux, signals, system, call

i'm creating a program. It creates some child processes. Child processes kill randomly other child processes in different rounds. After first round, some child processes are dead and others are still alive. So I created a "for" to wait child to finish:

```
for (i = 0; i < numChild; i++) {

      pidReturned[i] = wait(&returnValue[i]);

}
```

The problem is that not all processes die so I must tell the "father" that he must stop waiting for processes that won't die. I modified SIGALRM with sigaction to avoid it to kill my father. Then i call alarm(1); because i want to "wake up" the father. 
This only works if only a child is alive after first round, but if there's two or more the "for" is still waiting for all the processes that are still alive. So i don't know how to stop multiple waitS and not only one.
Ty for your attention

EDIT: All the wait part is like that:

```
sigemptyset(&block_kill);
sigaddset(&block_kill,SIGALRM);
sigaddset(&block_kill,SIGCHLD);

alarm(1);

sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &block_kill, NULL);

for (i = 0; i < numChild; i++) {

     pidReturned[i] = wait(&returnValue[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an alarm handler function, and inside the alarm handler function, set a global variable `interrupted` to 1.  Then in your for loop, you check `interrupted` on each iteration.  If `interrupted` is 1, you break out of the for loop.